# Convert/Cast generic Type to other by Linq Select statement

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I need an generic function to get data. In order to consume this I have to convert the type.

```
public IEnumerable<TOut> GetEntity<TIn, TOut>()
{
    var client = ... odata client
    var tInType = typeof(TIn).Name;

    var table = (DataServiceQuery<TIn>)client.GetType().GetProperty(tInType).GetValue(client);

    return table.ToList().Select(x=> (TOut)x).ToList(); <-- here is the error.
}
```

In the last line I get an error:

```
Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'TIn' to 'TOut'
```

I also tried  `.Select(x=> new (TOut)(x))` also fail.

Comment: Your table list of type "TIn" and you are trying to convert to TOut . This is not possible unless say, both are derived from same base class

Comment: They are not derived from same base class and it is not possible by design

Comment: It would be better if you were to write a generic Converter<TIn, TOut> function and use that. Dynamic casting anyways is dangerous.

Comment: The compiler is trying to save you from yourself. It has no knowledge that a `TIn` can be converted to a `TOut`, and so doesn't let you write that conversion. You're effectively trying to create a function with generic arguments which you'll always use "correctly" without the type system being able to verify it, the opposite of what we usually want in a language like C#. You can write `(TOut)(object)x` but you shouldn't.